# How to send ffmpeg output to framebuffer?

Tags: ffmpeg, mplayer

**How to send a ffmpeg stream to the framebuffer `/dev/fb0`?**

For instance, how to send the webcam output to the framebuffer?

I am looking for an equivalent of this `mplayer` command but using `ffmpeg` exclusively:

```
mplayer -ov fbdev2 -tv driver=v4l2 device=/dev/video0 tv://
```

---

P. S.: I don't wat to pipe the output of `ffmpeg` to `mplayer`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a lot of misinformation on the web about this not being possible, however, it most definitely is possible.  Note, you may need to adjust the `-i` and `-pix_fmt` a bit for your situation.

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt bgra -f fbdev /dev/fb0
```

Also note, the user executing this must have privileges to write to the framebuffer (i.e. root).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with solely ffmpeg. ffmpeg is a very fast video and audio converter, whilst mplayer is a video player (which involves video decoding, of course).